# SQL Partition Dates

Tags: sql

I have data such as this:

```
ID|From Date  |To Date
1 |01/01/2014 |04/01/2015
1 |04/01/2015 |01/01/2016
1 |01/01/2016 |12/31/2016
```

But I would like this as the end result:

```
ID|From Date  |To Date
1 |01/01/2014 |12/31/2016
```

I tried partitioning, but I'm not quite familiar with how it works. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This may be of some use: [Coalescing date ranges in postgres to eliminate overlaps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33829105/477563)

Comment: it looks more like a case of min(from date) max(to date) than partition

Comment: What would be returned if that second example row was missing, where you had a gap? And what would be returned if there was another row, which had a from/to date that overlapped date range of existing rows? (One special case example does not make for an effective specification.) And "I tried partitioning" is very scant on details of what you attempted. And which RDBMS... Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Teradata ???)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what should happen for each row, but if all you need is the oldest start date and newest end date for each ID...

```
SELECT ID
   , MIN([From Date]) AS [From Date]
   , MAX([To Date]) AS [To Date]
   FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

This will get you

```
1 | 01/01/2014 | 12/31/2016
```